# A is a mXn matrix, ind is a jX1 If i query v=a(id(j),:) why Matlab give me v=a(id(j+1),:)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a file that contain the data logged of 6 experiments with this information logged **"time ax ay az gx gy gz"**

I will call it logmpu6050 in my specific case a 26,220X7 matrix.

I can recognize every experiment because time restart from a lower random value from the previous. 
So when this condition is satisfied  **ti>ti+1** the data of the following experiment starts from the i+1 row.

I defined a "boundary vector"  **"ind"** that contains all this value, and i added the first (1,1) and the last value(end,1) of the first column of the logmpu6050 matrix because are two exeption that don't satisfy the condition.

But when i want to know for example,  this information:

```
query1=logmpu6050(ind(1),:)
```

**Matlab gave me  the values of the second row of ind, not the first, as you can see in the pic attached. Why?**

I also tought it could start counting from 0, but is false, Matlab dispalys an error message with the 0 value.

Thanks, always, for your time, my civil engineer background makes hard to solve this kind of problems.

[image: query]

Here the code i wrote.

```
%Open the file 
filename= uigetfile ('.txt');
fileID = fopen (filename);
logmpu6050 =csvread(filename);
fclose (fileID); 
n=length(logmpu6050);

%Count every time i>i+1 and store the entire raw value

ind=find(diff(logmpu6050(:,1))<0);  
ind=[logmpu6050(1,1);ind(:,:);logmpu6050(end,1)];
%No errors appear - logmpu6050 is a 26220X7 double - ind is a 7x1
ind
query1=logmpu6050(ind(1),:)
query2=logmpu6050(ind(2),:)
```

Comment: You're never adding 1 to `ind`. Look at `A = diff([1 2 1])`. Your new experiment starts at index `3` and your current `find` logic is going to give you `2`.

Comment: @excaza yes but to solve this problem `ind=find(diff(logmpu6050(:,1))<0);  
ind=[logmpu6050(1,1);ind(:,:);logmpu6050(end,1)];` this is why i have problems understanding my error :/

Comment: How does that solve the problem?

Comment: @excaza i though i could concatenate my ind matrix, adding the first value of `logmpu6050(1,1)` with the result of the find matrix `ind=find(diff(logmpu6050(:,1))<0); ` and the last value of the logmpu matrix  `logmpu6050(end,1)`  Doing so, only in my mind, I will have the boundary value of my experiments. The ind matrix contains this values, but when i query for the first it gives me the second.  I can't understand my logical mistake

Comment: @excaza i am a dude, i finally understood, my mistake, thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: @excaza  i modified the code, but i still make mistake `for ii=1:length(ind)-1
    expcell(ii)=logmpu6050(ind(ii):ind(ii+1),:)
end
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
same.
 `

Comment: Index into cells using `{}`

Comment: @excaza thanks! It works (finally)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative method could split the matrix into a cell array of submatrices:

```
% Generate an example
N = 3;  % Num of experiments
n = randi([2,5],N,1);  % Points per experiment
logmpu6050 = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) [(1:n(x))' x*ones(n(x),6)],1:N,'UniformOutput',0)');

% Find cut points
cuts = [diff(logmpu6050(:,1))<0;1];

% Split into a cell array
experiments = mat2cell(logmpu6050,diff([0;find(cuts)]));
```

Then you can access the submatrices like:

```
% The first experiment
experiments{1}

% The second experiment
experiments{2}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a lookup function would work nicely to pull out the submatrices you want.

Here's an example

```
% Generate an example data matrix
n = 3;  % Points per experiment
N = 3;  % Num of experiments
logmpu6050 = [repmat((1:n),1,N); repmat((1:n*N),6,1)]';

% Make a lookup function
lookup = @(x) cumsum([1;diff(logmpu6050(:,1))<0])==x;

% Get experiment 1 data
logmpu6050(lookup(1),:)

% Get experiment 2 data
logmpu6050(lookup(2),:)
```

This will output for the first experiment:

```
ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3     3     3
```

and for the second:

```
ans =

     1     4     4     4     4     4     4
     2     5     5     5     5     5     5
     3     6     6     6     6     6     6
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it @Teddy Ort I think i stil not very confident with indexing in Matlab, i studied the documentation, the advanced documentation, maybe i have to excercise more and be patient

Comment: is possible to create a loop that contains all the submatrix (not the orginal matrix) like `for ii=1:....-1          expcellmatrix(ii)=logmpu6050(lookup(ii),:)        end ` ? How can i do that? :) Thanks!

Comment: It's rarely necessary to use a loop in MATLAB. I'll post another answer to show how you can split the submatrices into a cell array